# How can vulnerability researchers find flaws in OSes / Embedded Systems?

Tags: operating-systems, reverse-engineering, embedded-system

Operating Systems and Embedded Systems usually don't come with source code or binaries that one can review.

How can a vulnerability researcher look for flaws in a system (Architecture, Protocols, etc.) without any access to source code?

Obviously, black box research will not produce good enough results.

Comment: Imagine an OS is like a human body. Just think about how germs/toxic get into your body.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you meant

Comment: Germs don't need to know how your body works, it just enters your body through wounds, foods, etc.  One doesn't need to know how the OS is built by constantly poking and punching any potential weak point.

Comment: "Obviously, Black box research will not produce good enough results." - citation needed

Comment: Learn reverse engineering.

Comment: I try to understand how without any binaries or source code, I can look for vulnerabilities in a system. I can not put an entire OS inside disassembler or debugger. poking the system is valuable approach, but is it the only/best approach ?

Comment: It all depends on the system. Look for some service listening on the network. Put that in a disassembler. Look at the libraries it links. Put them in a disassembler. Try fuzzing it and look at the crashes in a debugger. Look at the filesystem for setuid executables and analyze them. Etc. there's no need to put the _entire_ thing in a disassembler from busybox to the libc to the kernel. Just find the relevant parts of the OS and pay special attention to them.

Comment: I find it fascinating that your original question includes reverse engineering, then you state black-box analysis is not good enough. What do you *think* reverse engineering is?

Comment: black-box analysis  is amazing skill and knowledge, but sometimes, it is not enough. reverse engineering parts of the OS is the answer I actually expected, but how I will perform this when there is no binaries ?

Comment: @joe My answer literally explains how it is done. And what do you mean with "when there are no binaries"? Please give an example

Comment: for example, to find the set of bugs that created eternalblue you had somehow to investigate the code of the SMB service in windows machines. how one can do it?

Comment: `shodan search ash port:"23"` Pre Mirai era, finding vulnerable embedded systems used to be one my favorite pastimes.... But even today, they're usually running old Linux kernels, seldom receive software patches, use default passwords... just bundles of fun!

Comment: @joe The smb service is a binary like everything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question has many false assumptions, and these are the reason for your confusion.

> An OS doesn't come with source code or binaries.

Yes, it does. Open-Source Operating Systems like Linux come with source code, which is regularly looked at for possible vulnerabilities.

Closed-Source Operating Systems like Windows still come in binary form. If you install your operating system on a hard drive, this hard drive then contains all the code necessary to run the operating system. Furthermore, these binaries come in a specific architecture for the CPUs they are designed to run on. As such, anyone can look at the instructions that the Windows Kernel executes, as long as they have a copy of the operating system.

> Embedded Systems don't come with source code or binaries.

Embedded systems are a bit different than "regular" computers, and require specialized hardware to analyze. For example, to analyze a "custom" chip, researchers could dissolve the chip bit-by-bit and thus reverse engineer how the chip works.

> How can a researcher understand the underlying system?

Reverse engineering is a simple process: You observe the system, using knowledge you acquired analyzing similar systems, and see if you can draw conclusions from that. For example, when looking at communication between two chips, I can see that communication between two chips is always calling first, and the other chip always answer. The "caller" always sends data in a fixed width, while the "responder" sometimes sends data that's 8 bit long, sometimes 16, 32 or 64 bit long. Sometimes the answers are much longer.

Can you guess what the responder is? It's most likely some sort of storage.

As more and more of the communication is being observed, the "protocol" that is used to communicate can be deciphered. It doesn't need to be complete, but it could be observed that the communication is always in this form:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+------------+
| 2 Bytes | 4 Bytes | 2 Bytes | 8 Bytes | Variable Bytes | 0x00FF00FF |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+------------+
| Unknown | Unknown | Unknown | Length  | Payload        | EoT        |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+------------+
```

While you might not know yet what exactly these bytes mean, you can look at correlations between them. For example, you notice that the 8 bytes denote the length of the payload, followed by the payload, followed by the constant `0x00FF00FF`.

This process keeps going, until you can be reasonably sure that the "calls" and "responses" you see all make sense. You can then attempt to insert your own "calls" and see if the responses are what you expect them to be.

> Obviously, black box research will not produce good enough results.

The universe didn't come with a conveniently formatted man page, but we observed how things acted, drew hypotheses from that, made experiments and confirmed those hypotheses.

This allowed us to understand classical mechanics, thermodynamics, fluid mechanics, acoustics, optics and more. None of these things came with documentation, and they were essentially the same as a black box to us.

Reverse Engineering is the same thing. You observe, you hypothesize, you experiment, you succeed.

Comment: Most "custom" chips are just variations of ARM, MIPS or, in extreme cases, ARC. It's generally not necessary to do a complete chip-off analysis when the chip with high likelihood uses a well-known and public ISA.

Comment: @forest True, but I had something smaller in mind, like a custom DAC or some Op-Amp in a Tube Screamer, rather than a SoC.

Comment: Ah I see. So something you couldn't just attach a JTAG probe to.

Comment: @forest Yeah, my mind was really on something like a guitar pedal with some digital chip that does God-knows-what. My intention was to show that you *can* analyze what a chip does by looking at it. It's probably the most economic solution to see if it's similar enough to something pre-existing.

Comment: Thank you very much! but I still have to ask, some vulnerabilities for example are long chain of very specific low level bugs that creates the final big picture. its practically impossible to find them out of the blue. You can try, but sometimes you just must to get some technical information, those kind of things that happen inside the system, and not visible outside. thank you again!

Comment: @joe Yes, there are some obscure bugs, but then again if you spend enough time with the system, you understand how it works and what possible bugs there might be. It's like physicists theorizing the existence of a certain element and describing its properties, before it was ever successfully synthesized.

Comment: The missing piece for me is in the part you wrote"If you install your operating system on a hard drive, this hard drive then contains all the code necessary to run the operating system", Is there legitimate way to access to those files and put them in some disassembler? for example, in windows, ntoskrnl.exe+drivers contain all the machine code ? or there is parts of the OS that I unable to access them.

Comment: @joe I don't understand what you mean by "legitimate". Do you mean within Windows itself? In this case, this is not advised, because the OS controls what you see and what you don't see. If you analyze the storage medium, you only need to understand the file system structure.